# Запрос из таблицы SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, oracle

Делаю запрос из двух таблиц. В первой таблице есть колонки ФИО, Счет клиента и т.п.

На второй таблице есть адреса клиентов. В таблице адресов есть такие моменты что для одного клиента, один и тот же адрес завели два раза. И соответственно когда делаю запрос `SELECT` из этих таблиц, то в результате для каждой записи адреса повторяется ФИО клиента и Счет. Как сделать так чтоб они не повторялись?

`SELECT DICTINCT` не помог.

Выходить такой результат:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

А нужен такой результат:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: *для одного клиента, один и тот же адрес завели два раза ... Как сделать так чтоб они не повторялись?* Удалить ошибочные записи.

Comment: SQL server или Oracle? И добавьте в вопрос свой запрос, которому `SELECT DICTINCT не помог... :(`

Comment: *SELECT DICTINCT не помог* Значит, насчёт "один и тот же адрес" привираете - чем-то они отличаются.

Comment: для одного клиента, один и тот же адрес завели два раза ... Как сделать так чтоб они не повторялись? Удалить ошибочные записи.  - Да удалить можно, но есть такие моменты что у клиента сначала был один адрес, а потом у него поменялся. А старый адрес из базы мы не можем удалять...

Comment: "Как сделать так чтоб они не повторялись?" - а что вы желаете получить в результате, если они повторяются? Сделайте небольшой пример, с входными данными, желаемым результатом и запросом, как вы этого результата пытались достигнуть.

Comment: @0xdb Как сюда прикрепить скриншот желаемого результата? Снял скриншот, не могу привязать сюда...

Comment: @Cool_Dude Скриншот не нужен, здесь не картинная галерея. Скопируйте Ctrl+C и здесь вставте как текст Ctrl+V.

Comment: Нет, не комментарий, прямо в  вопрос кнопкой [править](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/posts/1004506/edit).

Comment: @0xdb, добавил в вопрос...

Comment: А покажите ка ваш селект, `DISTINCT` по какому полю делаете? Или вы пытаетесь заселектить с `DICTINCT` ???

Comment: SELECT DISTINCT FIO, ACCOUNT, NUM_DOG, VAL, OSTATOK, ADDRESS
FROM Main @Dmitry

Comment: @Cool_Dude не вижу, чтобы был запрос по двум таблицам, как вы в вопросе описали

Comment: так адреса разные, тут DISTINCT никак не поможет

Comment: @Dmitry я сюда добавил кусок, как Вы сказали, с distinct-ом...

Comment: @Cool_Dude вы пишете `Делаю запрос из двух таблиц.`, в вашем селекте я не вижу намека на запрос из двух таблиц, если хотите помощь, приложите полностью ваш селект

Comment: SELECT DISTINCT Main.FIO, Main.ACCOUNT, Main.NUM_DOG, Main.VAL, Main.OSTATOK, Main.Adres, Adres.ADDRESS FROM Main, Adres where Adres.CollectionID = Main.Adres - @Dmitry

Comment: @Cool_Dude так запрос получается все-таки по одной таблице будет?

Comment: По одной? Это как? В селекте же я выбираю из двух же?